# Apache: SSLCertificateKeyFile: file does not exist or is empty

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, mod-ssl

I am configuring SSL for `Apache 2`. My system is `Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS`. I have the following settings related to SSL in my vhost configuration:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.insecure.key
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/portal.selfsigned.crt
```

(Side note: I am using `.insecure` for the key file because the file is not passphrase-protected, and I like to clearly see that it is an insecure key file)

So, when I restart apache I get the following message:

```
Syntax error on line 39 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/500-portal-https:
SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/etc/ssl/private/server.insecure.key' does not exist or is empty
Error in syntax. Not restarting.
```

But the file is there, and is not empty (actually it contains a private key):

```
sudo ls -l /etc/ssl/private/server.insecure.key
-rw-r----- 1 root www-data 887 2012-08-07 15:14 /etc/ssl/private/server.insecure.key
sudo ls -ld /etc/ssl/private/
drwx--x--- 2 root www-data 4096 2012-08-07 13:02 /etc/ssl/private/
```

I have tried changing the ownership, using two groups www-data and ssl-cert. I am not sure which is the right one in Ubuntu: by default Ubuntu uses ssl-cert, but on the other hand the apache processes run with user www-data: it is started by user root, but changes to www-data at some point, and I am not sure when are the certificates read.

But anyway, changing the group owner has not improved the situation. My questions are:

1. What else could I try to get this working?
2. How can I verify that my keyfile is a valid keyfile?
3. How can I verify that the keyfile and the certificate (`/etc/ssl/certs/portal.selfsigned.crt`) work together?

I think that Apache is giving a misleading error message, and I would like to pinpoint the error.

Comment: Hello, could you mark this question as answered?

Comment: I should point out that I got this error message from the basic mistake of running `service apache2 restart` instead of `**sudo** service apache2 restart`... note to self: `sudo make me a sandwich fool`

Comment: I find the following article very helpful. I could not setup the system by this thread. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-debian-8

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I found the error. It was because I am using a script to setup the certificates, and one of the steps I am performing is `apache2ctl configtest`. The error was coming from this command, and not from apache restart, which was what was misleading me. Since I was running the apache2ctl command as normal user, it had no access the the keyfiles, and thus the error message.

Facit: make sure all your apache commands are run with sudo, even the ones which are only intended for syntax verification (`apache2ctl`), since they alse need access to the keys.

Comment: O yes, use `sudo`.

This line solved the issue.. Since I was running the apache2ctl command as normal user, it had no access the the keyfiles

Answer (score 19):

I also get the message

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile: file '/path/to/file' does not exist or is empty
```

while `/path/to/file` exist and have right permissions, just because of SELinux turned on and this file was unaccessable for apache user.

It looks like this:

```
$ sudo ls -laZ /etc/pki/tls/certs/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0      .
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0      ..
-rw-------. root root unconfined_u:object_r:cert_t:s0  this-one-works.crt
-rw-------. root root unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0 this-one-is-unaccessable.crt
```

To fix this, I run `sudo restorecon -Rv /etc/pki/tls/certs/` - it will repair SELinux property for the problem file.

Comment: it helped me for a certs not generated on that server but uploaded from other source

Comment: `sudo: restorecon: command not found`

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales `restorecon` is a part of `policycoreutils` package. Also you maybe don't have SELinux at all?

Answer (score 8):

I've done this and it helped me on CentOS 5.7

```
server:~ # chcon -t cert_t /etc/pki/tls/private/my.key 
server:~ # ls -laZ /etc/pki/tls/private/
```

Comment: It work for Centos. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar message:

`SSLCertificateChainFile: file '/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/DigiCertCA.crt\xe2\x80\x9d' does not exist or is empty`

My problem was the text editor I was using placed a "right quote" ascii 148 instead of a normal double quote ascii 34; using a unix-type editor (e.g. TextWrangler) put in the right quote and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No permission for normal users in `/etc/ssl/private` directory.

Please try

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are wrong, but according to your answer it wasn't the cause of the problem :

`drwx--x--- 2 root www-data 4096 2012-08-07 13:02 /etc/ssl/private/`

/etc/ssl/private usually belongs to group ssl-cert on debian based systems.

Just noticed the 0710 perms and wonder what it can be used for.

Comment: Your are probably right, it should be at least 0750. I have been trying different things, and the status I posted is probably not the most correct one. Running apache2ctl as root has for sure solved my problems.

Comment: 0710 is just fine, you need to know the file name to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Me too, I got this error message when I checked the httpd syntax :

SSLCertificateFile: file 'C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/conf/key/certificate.crt\xe2\x80\x9c' does not exist or is empty

My problem was the "double Quote" I had pasted. So I deleted it and typed it, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this can also happen if your key file contains extra stuff before the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` line